# How to determine the frequency of input signal from Sensor to ADC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, aliasing

I am using a [Pressure Sensor](https://net.grundfos.com/Appl/ccmsservices/public/literature/filedata/Grundfosliterature-4925253.pdf) that gives out an Analog Output of 0V to 10V depending upon the sensed pressure.

I am trying to design a filter (or at least determine some starting RC values) for the anti-aliasing stage before the signal from the sensor is fed into my ADC.

Is the frequency 0V, i.e. DC here?

[image]

My specific question is - what is the bandwidth / frequency range at which I need to evaluate the driving Op Amp A1 at?

[image]

Comment: to avoid aliasing, use fs/2 or lower

Comment: I think you need to look at the response time as given in the datasheet.  If it takes the sensor 100 milliseconds to respond to changes in the pressure, then a cutoff of 10Hz  would be reasonable.  If you are using a low speed ADC, they often include oversampling and implement an antialiasing filter for the real sampling rate in software - a simple RC low pass for 10Hz would then do the job.

Comment: By the way, your link is broken. I found the datasheet anyway, but others are more inclined to just skip a question entirely if they have to go searching for stuff.

Comment: @JRE Thanks for the tip to look up how quickly the sensor output can change. That is my signal frequency. Basic, but I was missing that concept. I now how to start picking my parts. You can add that as the answer and I will accept.

Comment: you appear to have linked to a file downloaded onto your machine! Try linking to somewhere on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at the response time as given in the datasheet. 
If it takes the sensor 100 milliseconds to respond to changes in the pressure, then a cutoff of 10Hz would be reasonable.

If you are using a low speed ADC, they often include oversampling and implement an antialiasing filter for the real sampling rate in software - a simple RC low pass for 10Hz would then do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you want the filter to pass the signal of interest, and greatly attenuate any signal greater than half the sample rate of the ADC. So there are the two main constraints. The greater the separation between the two, the easier your job is. Most of the time when I have had to do this, in relatively undemanding applications, the characteristics of the noise were not well known, so I could not follow the formalized filter design process. Instead, I just assumed I could get away with one or two stages of RC filter.

If you use a simple RC filter (or op-amp with RC response), then start off by making the cutoff 0.1 of the sampling rate. Then check if it is 10x the signal bandwidth. If it satisfies both constraints, then you probably are OK. These are just easy constraints. Nothing official or magic. If you cannot satisfy these constraints, then place RC as close to the bandwidth limit as you can without attenuating the signal too much, then test to see if performance is acceptable.

If you don't know the bandwidth of the signal (which seems to be the case for the OP), you can consider signal rise time instead of the signal bandwidth. To make sure your signal is not attenuated, you would like the RC filter to have an RC constant smaller than the rise time of the signal. If you don't know the rise time of the signal, maybe you can do some basic measurements first to establish it. Or use the worst-case assumption that the rise time is the same as the actual quantity being measured (pressure in this case).

Because ADC inputs typically have such high impedance, you can often cascade two or even three stages of RC filter, where each stage has the same time constant, but 10x the resistance. For example 100 Ohms/1uF followed by 1k/0.1uF followed by 10k/0.01uF.

A final word on realistic component values. The capacitor is in parallel with the input capacitance of the ADC. It works out best if the filter capacitor is much bigger than the input capacitance, so that you can ignore the input capacitance. In some cases, you could let the input capacitance be the C in the RC filter. But this would require you to know the input capacitance.

The resistors used in RC filters for ADC's must be much smaller than the input resistance of the ADC. I have seen ADC's where the input resistance is not specified. You can measure it with a meter if you have hardware. Typical values are 100k to 500k.

All of this assumes you are running a non-critical operation. If you are designing something VERY critical, you should hire a consultant and go through a more rigorous design process. Or plan to implement a very rigorous test to validate the design.